# Why is $\ln(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})=-\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$?

Tags: logarithms

In a recent discussion thread, I came across an observation that $$\ln(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1})=\pm\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$$
Since it's straightforward that $\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})=+\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$, proving the above statement boils down to showing that $$\ln(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})=-\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$$ However, I'm having a difficult time solving this puzzle. What's the catch?

Comment: Hint : $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2 - y^2$ and $\log(\frac{1}{a})=-\log a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ln(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})=-\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$

because $\ln(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})+\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$

$=\ln[(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})]=\ln[a^2-(a^2-1)]=\ln1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It's because
$$\left(a-\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)\left(a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)=1,$$
at least for $a>1$.